# Force applied by horizontal wind on object

Tags: forces, gravity, drag, aerodynamics

[image]

Hello, I have a question for a project I'm currently doing:

In a tunnel with no gravity, there is a constant wind blowing through.
A sphere in the middle of the tunnel is completely motionless to start with, but obviously will experience a force from the wind and start moving in the same direction.

What function can I use to express force over time on the sphere by the wind? What about speed of the sphere over time? 
What if instead the sphere is in free fall with the same horizontal wind?

I would love to learn more about air drag for a situation like this, I'd appreciate any links to further reading material.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics) should tell you all you need to know.

Comment: I've been reading this and searching all over the Internet looking for an explanation and I can't seem to find a simple solution for my problem. Do you have anything more specific or easier to understand?